# Why does !heap -s heap not work the way intended?

Tags: windbg

My WinDBG version is 10.0.10240.9 AMD64 and while casually debugging some native memory dump I realized that my !heap command behaves different than described and I am unable to figure out why.

There are plenty of resources mentioning `!heap -s`:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
- http://windbg.info/doc/1-common-cmds.html

When I execute `!heap -s`

I get this truncated list:

```
0:000> !heap -s

************************************************************************************************************************
                                              NT HEAP STATS BELOW
************************************************************************************************************************
LFH Key                   : 0x000000c42ceaf6ca
Termination on corruption : ENABLED
          Heap     Flags   Reserv  Commit  Virt   Free  List   UCR  Virt  Lock  Fast 
                            (k)     (k)    (k)     (k) length      blocks cont. heap 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Virtual block: 0000000003d40000 - 0000000003d40000 (size 0000000000000000)
... many more virtual blocks
0000000000b90000 00000002 3237576 3220948 3237576  20007  1749   204  359      0   LFH
0000000000010000 00008000      64      8     64      5     1     1    0      0      
... more heaps
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Ok fine, `b90000` looks big but contrary to those docs above and `!heap -s -?` I cannot get information for this heap, each of those commands produce the exact same output as seen above (as if I would not specify anything after -s):

```
!heap -s b90000
!heap -s -h b90000
!heap -s 1
```

I get a load of virtual blocks and a dump of **all** heaps instead of the single specified one.

Anyone having the same issue?

Comment: try latest Windbg from Insider Preview SDK Build 14965 : https://software-download.microsoft.com/pr/Windows_InsiderPreview_SDK_en-us_14965.iso?t=88bf7144-c840-4a35-9761-5776e3465d5b&e=1480779143&h=43050afd20d55e08e2c5928966297243

Comment: Why questions are hard to answer... It's also broken in 10.0.10075.9, 10.0.10586.567, 10.0.14321.1024. It works in 6.3.9600.17298.

Comment: @magicandre1981 official WDK release 14321.1024 does work, but only with `-h heap` syntax.

Comment: @ThomasWeller tested  10.0.14321.1024, works with `!heap -s -h <heap>`, works.

Comment: My test results are from Windows 7 SP1 x64. Are you on Windows 10?

Comment: @ThomasWeller, tested it at home on 10, which was working. Going to update WinDBG at work on Win7 to see if it does. Too bad if it doesn't but good point.

Comment: @ThomasWeller The debugger available online 14321.1024 x64 does work on my win 7 machine when I walk the heap with the additional -h param.

Comment: @Samuel: thanks for the feedback. I'll try again

Comment: Note to myself: Don't call this on a 3gb heap. WinDBG walks the heap single-threaded and is already several hours busy on that.

Answer (score 1):

My "Windows Debugger Version 10.0.10586.567 AMD64" behaved like yours, but
“Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.3.9600.16384 AMD64”  I have in in:
 C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x64

```
0:000> !heap -s -h 0000000000220000 
Walking the heap 0000000000220000 ..................Virtual block: 0000000015f20000 - 0000000015f20000 (size 0000000000000000)
Virtual block: 000000001b2e0000 - 000000001b2e0000 (size 0000000000000000)
Virtual block: 000000001f1e0000 - 000000001f1e0000 (size 0000000000000000)
Virtual block: 0000000023c10000 - 0000000023c10000 (size 0000000000000000)
Virtual block: 000000001c060000 - 000000001c060000 (size 0000000000000000)
Virtual block: 000000001ddc0000 - 000000001ddc0000 (size 0000000000000000)

 0: Heap 0000000000220000
   Flags          00000002 - HEAP_GROWABLE 
   Reserved memory in segments              226880 (k)
   Commited memory in segments              218204 (k)
   Virtual bytes (correction for large UCR) 218740 (k)
   Free space                               12633 (k) (268 blocks)
   External fragmentation          5% (268 free blocks)
   Virtual address fragmentation   0% (30 uncommited ranges)
   Virtual blocks  6 - total 0 KBytes
   Lock contention 0
   Segments        1

   Low fragmentation heap   00000000002291e0
       Lock contention        0
       Metadata usage     90112 bytes
       Statistics:
           Segments created     993977
           Segments deleted     992639
           Segments reused           0
       Block cache:
         3:         1024 bytes (    17,     0)
         4:         2048 bytes (    42,     0)
         5:         4096 bytes (   114,     0)
         6:         8192 bytes (   231,     2)
         7:        16384 bytes (   129,     9)
         8:        32768 bytes (   128,    11)
         9:        65536 bytes (   265,    58)
        10:       131072 bytes (   357,     8)
        11:       262144 bytes (   192,    49)

       Buckets info:
  Size   Blocks  Seg  Empty  Aff    Distribution
------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------

                    Default heap   Front heap       Unused bytes
   Range (bytes)     Busy  Free    Busy   Free     Total  Average 
------------------------------------------------------------------ 
     0 -   1024      577    140 1035286  11608   10563036     10
  1024 -   2048      173      3    586    374      27779     36
  2048 -   3072       17     19     47    224       1605     25
  3072 -   4096       20     12      1    126        348     16
  4096 -   5120       35      3      1     30        677     18
  5120 -   6144        2      8      0      0         33     16
  6144 -   7168        5      9      0      0         56     11
  7168 -   8192        0     11      0      0          0      0
  8192 -   9216       14      0      0     15        236     16
  9216 -  10240        1      0      0      0          8      8
 12288 -  13312        1      0      0      0         17     17
 14336 -  15360        1      0      0     18          1      1
 15360 -  16384        1      0      0      0         32     32
 16384 -  17408       10      0      0      0        160     16
 22528 -  23552        1      0      0      0          9      9
 23552 -  24576        2      0      0      0         32     16
 27648 -  28672        1      0      0      0          8      8
 30720 -  31744        0      1      0      0          0      0
 32768 -  33792       18      0      0      0        250     13
 33792 -  34816        0      1      0      0          0      0
 39936 -  40960        0      2      0      0          0      0
 40960 -  41984        0      1      0      0          0      0
 43008 -  44032        0      2      0      0          0      0
 44032 -  45056        0      5      0      0          0      0
 45056 -  46080        0      1      0      0          0      0
 46080 -  47104        0      2      0      0          0      0
 47104 -  48128        0      1      0      0          0      0
 49152 -  50176        0      3      0      0          0      0
 50176 -  51200        1      0      0      0         16     16
 51200 -  52224        0      4      0      0          0      0
 57344 -  58368        0      1      0      0          0      0
 58368 -  59392        0      1      0      0          0      0
 62464 -  63488        0      1      0      0          0      0
 63488 -  64512      200      1      0      0       3200     16
 64512 -  65536        0      1      0      0          0      0
 65536 -  66560     1029      2      0      0      10624     10
 79872 -  80896      100      0      0      0        900      9
131072 - 132096        9      0      0      0        144     16
193536 - 194560        1      0      0      0          9      9
224256 - 225280        1      0      0      0         16     16
262144 - 263168       49     27      0      0        784     16
327680 - 328704        1      0      0      0         17     17
384000 - 385024        0      1      0      0          0      0
523264 - 524288        1      5      0      0         23     23
------------------------------------------------------------------ 
  Total             2271    268 1035921  12395   10610020     10
```

This might be a walkaround,
can’t answer why the win 10 version don’t work :-(